# Problem calling a function from another script to change the UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to change a UI element of the canvas using TextMeshPro and 2 scripts. I have a function that works at the end of a class that destroy the game object of one of the players (its local multiplayer), finds which player it is and attempts to lead to a Score script. Up till that point it works and the check for player works as it prints a debug showing who won that round, however I'm getting an error telling me

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Tank.Destroy () (at Assets/Scripts/Tank.cs:147)

Here's the Destroy function, it works all the way through and fails at the attempt to link to PlayerOne/PlayerTwoScored

```
 public void Destroy()
     {

         Debug.Log(this.gameObject + " has died" );
         Destroy(this.gameObject);
         GameObject effect = Instantiate(hitEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
         Destroy(effect, 10f);
         SceneManager.LoadScene(Application.loadedLevel);

         Score s = gameObject.GetComponent<Score>();
         if (this.gameObject.name.Contains("Tank Player 1"))
         {
             Debug.Log("Player Two wins!");
             s.PlayerTwoScored();
         }
         else if (this.gameObject.name.Contains("Tank Player 2"))
         {
             Debug.Log("Player One wins!");
             s.PlayerOneScored();
         }
         else { return; }

     }
```

Here's the code for the score script

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using TMPro;

 public class Score : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int scoreValue1 = 0;
     public int scoreValue2 = 0;
     public TMP_Text score1;
     public TMP_Text score2;

     public void PlayerOneScored() {
         Debug.Log("Player One Scored");
         score1 = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
         score1.text = "P1 Score: " + scoreValue1;

     }

     public void PlayerTwoScored()
     {
         Debug.Log("Player Two Scored");
         score2 = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
         score2.text = "Score: " + scoreValue2;
     }
 }
```

Included I have a picture of the log, and the UI showing the script and the TMP text objects in the canvas.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJVdM.png)

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmwt8.png)

***Update*** : I checked up other question threads and assumed that my problem with this was the fact that i used

```
Score s = gameObject.GetComponent<Score>();
```

When i should have used

```
Score s = new Score();
```

As Score is not attached to the same gameObject but a UI element (The canvas and the 2 Text files as seen in image). I'm not sure how to associate it with this. 
I assumed my above code was correct at the time but i am now getting this error

> NullReferenceException
>   UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent[T] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Component.bindings.cs:42)
>   Score.PlayerOneScored () (at Assets/Scripts/Score.cs:16)
>   Tank.Destroy () (at Assets/Scripts/Tank.cs:147)

Line 16 in Score is

```
score1 = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
```

And line 147 in Tank is

> s.PlayerOneScored();

Comment: What is line 147 of your Tank.cs code? Is a hitEffect prefab in the inspector?

Comment: @ErikOverflow Yes thats a hit effect prefab, that works fine

Comment: No, I am asking you if you have assigned the prefab in the inspector for your Tank code @ConorKeaney

Comment: @ErikOverflow Oh sorry! Misread that. Line 147 is. s.PlayerOneScored();

Comment: Updated my post with changes